# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, object-oriented-analysis

I have the following methods inside my asp.net mvc class:-

```
public class Crud
{
    Repository repository = new Repository();

   List<string> activeTech = repository.getAll().ToList();
```

but I am getting the following exception :-

```
Error   1   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property
```

but If add static to my code as follow, the exception will be removed :-

```
public class Crud    {
   static Repository repository = new Repository();

   List<string> activeTech = repository.getAll().ToList();
```

so can anyone advice on this please?

Thanks

Comment: Surely you'd want your second statement to be within a method?

Answer (score 2):

Initialization of fields in classes is done directly before the code of your constructor is executed. At this time, there is no `this` reference yet.

So field initialization is executed in a *static* context and you are not allowed to access any other *instance* members of the class.

To solve this, you could move the initialization of `activeTech` inside your constructor:

```
public class CRUD
{
    Repository repository = new Repository(); 
    List<string> activeTech;

    public CRUD()
    {
       activeTech = repository.getAll().ToList();
    }
}
```

because at the time the constructor code gets executed, a `this` reference is accessible and you're no longer in a static context.

---

Note that the class name `CRUD` does not match C# naming conventions that suggest UpperCamelCase (`Crud`) for class names.

Comment: @JohnJohn because `static` members _can_ be accessed in a static `context`.

Comment: the problem I am confused is that when I added breakpoints to my shared methods and variables, and I run my project using Visual Studio ,, then Visual studio will never stop at any breakpoint which is related to a static member ,so it is hard to understand how the flow goes on,, so is there a specific reason that VS will never stop on a breakpoint which is related to a static member ?